# Typing in Module Printf

Tags: types, ocaml

In the document of [Module Printf](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Printf.html), I don't understand the mechanism of `('a, out_channel, unit) format`, thought I use that a lot in practice.

For instance, the following functions type well while compiling:

```
type t =
  { x: int;
    y: int }

let print (chan: out_channel) (co: t) : unit =
  Printf.fprintf chan "(%d, %d)" x y

let try (co0: t) (co1: t) =
  Printf.fprintf Pervasives.stdout "From %a To %a" print co0 print co1
```

The signature of `Printf.fprintf` is `: out_channel -> ('a, out_channel, unit) format -> 'a`, but I don't see what `('a, out_channel, unit) format` matches in `"From %a To %a" print co0 print co1`.

Also, the signature of `print` is `out_channel -> t -> unit`, why is `print co0 print co1` acceptable in the code?

In one word, could anyone explain how `Printf.fprintf Pervasives.stdout "From %a To %a" print co0 print co1` is typed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OCaml has a typing hack around format strings. This is weird but useful for its easy and type-safe printf functions.

Usually, string literals are typed as strings:

```
# "(%d, %d)";;
- : string = "(%d, %d)"
```

But they are NOT if they are with a "formatting" type context:

```
# ( "(%d, %d)" : (_,_,_) format );;
- : (int -> int -> 'a, 'b, 'a) format = <abstr>
```

OCaml type checker looks at the literal as a format string then uses a special typing rule for it: it finds two `%d` there, and give a type `(int -> int -> 'a, 'b, 'a) format` which means it is a format string which can take 2 integers and do something.

Using string literals with Printf functions gives the same "format" typing context so "(%d, %d)" is typed not as a mere string but this format type:

```
# Printf.fprintf stdout "(%d, %d)";;
- : int -> int -> unit = <fun>
```

`(t1, t2, t3) format` roughly has the following meaning:

- t1 is for how the format string behaves as a function: "%d" should have "int -> t" for some type t in this t1 part since it takes an integer and do something (mainly printing).
- t2 is the type for the channel
- t3 is the final result type when all the format parameters are given.

You can verify it as follows:

```
# (fun x -> Printf.fprintf stdout x, x) "(%d, %d)";;
- : (int -> int -> unit) * (int -> int -> unit, out_channel, unit) format =
(<fun>, <abstr>)
```

`"(%d, %d)"` is used here to take 2 integer parameters and it is used to send a string to stdout whose type is `out_channel`, then finally it returns `unit`.

Actually `format` type is just an alias of `format6` with 6 type parameters and these 3 more type parameters are used for other format string typing hacks. But we do not go futher from here.

So now for "%a".

```
# ( "%a" : (_, out_channel, unit) format);;
- : ((out_channel -> 'a -> unit) -> 'a -> unit, out_channel, unit) format = <abstr>
```

This tells you `Printf.fprintf stdout "%a"` takes two parameters. The one is a function of type `out_channel -> 'a -> unit` and the other is `'a`.

If you see this type then it is easy to see `Printf.fprintf stdout "%a" print co0` is well-typed. Note that it is NOT `Printf.fprintf stdout "%a" (print co0)` (this is what I wrongly read when I saw `"%a"` at the first time years ago.)

`Printf.fprintf stdout "%a" print co0` tries to print `co0` with the printer `print`. The channel for this sub-printing is of course `stdout` which is given to `Printf.fprintf`.

Comment: Since OCaml 4.02, there are no longer any hack for typing format strings: format strings are desugared to a normal GADT (by the typechecker, so there is still a bit of magic but only at the syntactic level).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75907704/7943564 for @octachron's updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'll describe my intuition, someone who knows how things really work can correct me or provide a better answer. `('a, out_channel, unit) format` is a type provided for a format string. A format string is not parsed as a string, i.e. it does not have type `string`. Rather, for example `"From %a To %a"` is parsed to have type `((('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'b -> ('a -> 'd -> 'c) -> 'd -> 'c), 'a, 'c) format`. When you unify this with `('a, out_channel, unit) format` you get `(((out_channel -> 'b -> unit) -> 'b -> (out_channel -> 'd -> unit) -> 'd -> unit), out_channel, unit) format`. Therefore the type of `Printf.fprintf Pervasives.stdout "From %a To %a"` is `(out_channel -> 'b -> unit) -> 'b -> (out_channel -> 'd -> unit) -> 'd -> unit`, i.e. it takes four arguments just like the `print co0 print co1` arguments.