# How can I understand the type of Printf.printf?

Tags: types, ocaml

How can I understand the type of `Printf.printf`?

```
Printf.printf ;;
- : ('a, out_channel, unit) format -> 'a = <fun>
```

knowing that `Printf.printf "%n"` is a function of type `int -> unit`, and `Printf.printf "%s"` is a function of type `string -> unit`.

Comment: It cannot: the answer is out-of-date and does not describe the current implementation of `Printf` and `Format` that are GADT based.

Comment: @octachron It is still a duplicate. If the current answers don't apply anymore, than someone should either expand the existing answers, or add a new answer with the up-to-date information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Printf` functions are interpreters for a GADT-based DSL.

An important point is that the argument of those functions are format strings which are GADTs with some syntactic sugar to make then appear as string literals. Typically, `"%s"` is a shorthand for:

```ml
let x =
  let open CamlinternalFormatBasics in
  Format (String (No_padding, End_of_format), "%s")
```

as you can check by evaluating

```ml
open CamlinternalFormatBasics
let x: _ format6 = "%s"
```

in the REPL.
Similarly `"%s %d"` can be expanded into:

```ml
  Format
   (String (No_padding,
     Char_literal (' ', Int (Int_d, No_padding, No_precision, End_of_format))),
   "%s %d")
```

Going one step further, the type of `"%s"` is `(string -> 'a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'd, 'a)` format6 the first and sixth type parameters describe respectively the type of the interpreters applied to the format string and the final return type. In other words, this type means that `Printf.printf "%s"` is expecting one string argument before returning its final argument.

How does that DSL work? It is much easier to try to understand on a simpler DSL, for instance:

```ml
type 'a fmt =
| Lit: string * 'a fmt -> 'a fmt
| Hole: 'a fmt -> (string -> 'a) fmt
| Start : unit fmt
```

Here, we are defining our own format string as a sequence of either literals or holes. For instance,

```ml
let text = Lit ("Hello", Start)
let text_with_hole = Lit("Hello", Hole (Lit ("!", Start)))
```

then interpreting the format string is a matter of filling out the holes with contents.

```ml
let rec printf: type a. a fmt -> a = function
| Start -> ()
| Lit (l,rest) -> print_string l; printf rest
| Hole rest ->
  fun s -> print_string s; printf rest
```

And we can check that this basic `printf` function has the behavior that we wanted. First, we cant print `text` without the need for more argument:

```
let () = printf text
```

Second, we need to fill one hole before printing the `text_with_hole` format string:

```
let () = printf text_with_hole "world"
```

The `Format`, `Printf` and `Scanf` modules in the OCaml standard library are built upon this idea (but with many layers of added complexity in order to extend the set of supported features).